# Java error when trying to run executable jar files

Tags: java, file, jar, executable

Alright, so whenever I try to open an executable JAR file, it loads for awhile then gives me an error saying it can't launch the application. Then, when I click on more details, the first tab is random markings and spam, and the second tab gives me this:

[image]

I'm no computer expert whatsoever, but I was told to reinstall Java, which I did many times, but to no avail. This is my last resort. Can anybody please help?

Comment: can you share the manifest.mf file's content from the .jar file?

Comment: There is no manifest.mf file. :(

Comment: There should be one under META-INF directory inside the jar. Without which your jar won't run.

Comment: It isn't just with one jar file though, I'd like for it to work with every jar file. And I wouldn't want to have to edit the meta-inf things every time I found a new one.

Comment: And if this is what you meant by share, here you go http://prntscr.com/cyy7m

Comment: No.  A screenshot of the Windows 'file info' for the Jar is not what @galuano1 was referring to.  The manifest is inside the Jar, called MANIFEST-MF (?) and contains text information that includes the name of the class to run when 'double clicked'.  If the Jars do not have a manifest, they were not meant to be run that way.

Comment: They have Manifests, but they don't open when I run them.

Comment: do a 'jar -xvf <jarname.jar> META-INF/' on command prompt. This should extract the contents in META-INF dir, and you should be able see the manifest.mf file

Answer (score 0):

Click Start Menu> Control Panal > Java > Select "General tab" then in "Temporary Internet Files" click "settings" button and than click "Delete Files" and after that click "Restore Defaults."